# explicit group cocycles of the Klein four-group

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Using the Kunneth Theorem and Universal Coefficients Theorem, one can compute
$$H^3(\mathbb{Z}/2\times\mathbb{Z}/2;\mathbb{Z})\simeq\mathbb{Z}/2,$$
$$H^5(\mathbb{Z}/2\times\mathbb{Z}/2;\mathbb{Z})\simeq\mathbb{Z}/2\times\mathbb{Z}/2.$$
What are examples of explicit group cocycles that represent these cohomology classes?